# Store row number as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have to apply a formula to a column from row number 1 to the row where the max value is located. So if in column A the max value is at row number 8, I need to apply the formula to A1:A8.

I have created a variable range that works, but I dont know how to create the variable rowMax which is the row number of the max value in the column. Any ideas?? Thanks

```
Dim rowMax As Long
rowMax = ??????    
Dim TMaxRange As Range
Set TMaxRange = Range("A1:A" & rowMax)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Application.WorkSheetFunction.Match()` and  `Application.WorkSheetFunction.Max()`

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction    
    rowMax = .Match(.Max(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")),ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"),0)
End With
```